# 近所に as an adverb

Tags: grammar

近所に刑務所ができることになって、少し不安です. In this sentence is 近所に working as an adverb? Since 近所 could be a na-adjective

Answer (score 3):

近所【きんじょ】 is not a *-na* adjective, but rather a noun, meaning "neighborhood, vicinity, the nearby area".  See [the Weblio EJ entry](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E8%BF%91%E6%89%80), for instance.

Answer (score 3):

The に in 近所に points to the location where the prison will be built (刑務所ができる).