# 直前に adverb or not

Tags: grammar

> デートを**直前に**キャンセルして、彼女をかんかんに怒らせてしまいました。

In this example is 直前に an adverb?

Answer (score 6):

直前に is [**adverbial**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_phrase) because it modifies some verb, but it's not a (single-word) **adverb**. 直前に is a **phrase** made of two words (a noun 直前 and a particle に), so it doesn't make much sense to ask if it's an adverb or not in the first place. (By the way, [近所に](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/72109/5010) also is an adverbial phrase, but not an adverb.)

To take an example in English, "at night" as in "I sleep at night" is an adverbial phrase, but neither "at" nor "night" is an adverb by itself.

Unequivocal (single-word) adverbs in Japanese are words like ゆっくり, とても and ようやく.

Comment: how to remember all those types of adverbial phrases? where can i found the list

Comment: @Sam You can't, because there are almost an infinite number of possible adverbial phrases. Still you have to remember common "set" phraaes like 夜に ("in the evening") one by one.